# Can we read a .csv file by a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to run this below ui.r and server.r on rstudio but as I run the app the window gets opened and closed on its own.

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

library(ggplot2)

library(dplyr)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel(h3("Choose a Project")),

      sidebarLayout(

       sidebarPanel(

          br(),
          selectInput("select_p",label=h3("Choose a Project   Name"),choices=c(data$project_name)),

          br(),

          radioButtons("color","Choose a Color" ,choices =c("Green","Yellow","Red"))
       ),

       mainPanel(

         plotOutput("table")
       )
     ))
)
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)

library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)

library(ggplot2)


data <- read.csv(file = "data.csv", na.strings =c("", "NA"))

call <- data.frame(data)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


   dataset <- reactive({ data%>%
        filter(project_name==input$select_p)%>%
        group_by(project_id)%>%
        summarise(count=n())

   })

   output$table <- renderPlot({



       plot(data[,input$assesor_id],
        main=input$name,
        ylab="Number of Discharges",
        xlab="Discharge Type")     
   })
})
```

I have count the number of assessments conducted by each assessors in each project and to plot a graph

error -

Warning: Error in pairs.default: only one column in the argument to 'pairs'

Stack trace (innermost first):

```
80: pairs.default
79: pairs
78: plot.data.frame
77: plot
76: renderPlot [F:\R\Navriti\plots/server.R#30]
68: output$table
 1: runApp
```

Comment: Please consider formating your code so it is easier to read.

Comment: `setwdlibrary(shiny)`, is this a typo?

Comment: No its an in built library function....to the best of my knowledge

Comment: There ist `setwdlibrary` in base R, may be you miss something

Comment: I will replace with library(Shiny)  and run it........but is it necessary to use library function in server.r  ?

Comment: FWIW, [shiny cheatsheet](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/cheatsheet.html) mentions you should load data before calling `shinyServer()`.

Comment: thanks ....but the code is still not working

Comment: If the application window opens and closes that quickly, there should be some error message(s) printed to the R Console.  Those wold be helpful in determining what went wrong.

Comment: This the error which is taking place